# Finding best speed and accuracy combination for parsing

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have experience on different cases englishPCFG pos-tagger is more accurate then any others. The model used on http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

Due to speed, I would like to get parse result with depparse (english_UD)

Is there a way to use englishPCFG pos-tagger (without parse as it is slow to compare with english_UD) with depparse to combine pos-tagger accuracy and depparse speed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The parser produces a part-of-speech tag sequence as a part of its total parsing process.  You cannot get the tag sequence without completely parsing the sentence.

Your best bet is to use a Stanford CoreNLP pipeline, use the dedicated part-of-speech tagger and the neural network dependency parser in the pipeline.

`-annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse`